# Cocoapods pod creates target and when used changes target in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I created a private pod with Cocoapods. The pod has a dependency.

When I use this pod in my Xcode project, Xcode's scheme now defaults to "MyPodName (Pods Project)" instead of my app's target after running `pod install`. This is somewhat annoying because I have to go change the scheme back everytime I run `pod install` because different branches may have differences in `Podfile.lock`

I created my Pod using the Cocoapods skeleton generated by `pod lib create`.

Here is my podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = "MyPodLib"
  s.version          = "2.0.0"
  s.summary          = "MyPodLib is just an example name for this question."

  s.description      = <<-DESC
                       DESC

  s.homepage         = "https://github.com/username/MyPodLib"
  s.license          = 'License'
  s.author           = { "username" => "email@address.com" }
  s.source           = { :git => "https://github.com/username/MyPodLib.git", :tag => s.version.to_s }

  s.platform     = :ios, '8.4'
  s.requires_arc = true

  s.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*'
  s.resource_bundles = {
    'MyPodLib' => ['Pod/Assets/*.png']
  }

  s.dependency 'DependencyPod', '2.0.0'
end
```

I think this might only be happening on my computer too. Colleague says doesn't happen to him.

Comment: I have the same problem, as do my colleagues. My current avenue of investigation is getting `pod` to stop generating schemes in general, since I don't think they're necessary. If schemes must be created, I'd like to uncheck the "Show" bit (visible in Manage Schemes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cocoapods developers introduced this behavior when they added sharing of schemes for development pods in [this pull request](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/3600). Your colleague may have been using an earlier version of Cocoapods, since that PR was only merged in May 2015.

The schemes generated by `pod` are set to be both shared and visible, and no option is available to change this behavior. We're not the only ones with this problem ([1](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3766), [2](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3165), [3](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3824)).

One Cocoapods developer subsequently released a [plugin](https://github.com/orta/cocoapods-no-dev-schemes) that's supposed to remove the schemes (literally by [`rm`-ing](https://github.com/orta/cocoapods-no-dev-schemes/blob/master/lib/cocoapods_plugin.rb) the shared schemes after they're created). I say supposed to, because I have not yet figured out how to make the thing work from the instructions provided.

Edit: The same developer now [confirms](https://github.com/orta/cocoapods-no-dev-schemes/issues/3) that the plugin may not work as expected.

Comment: Colleague using same version